# Using protractor to test infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ng-grid

I don't think this is strictly infinite scrolling but it was the best i could think of that compares to what i am seeing.

Anyway, we are using ng-grid to show data in a table. We have roughly 170 items (rows) to display. when we use ng-grid it creates a repeater. When i inspect this repeater from the browser its limited to 35 items and, as you scroll down the list, you start to lose the top rows from the dom and new rows are added at the bottom etc (hence why i don't think its strictly infinite scrolling as that usually just adds more rows)

Just so I'm clear there is always 35 `'ng-repeat=row in rendered rows'` elements in the dom no matter how far you have scrolled down.

This is great until it comes to testing. I need to get the text for every item in the list, but using `element.all(by.binding('item.name'))` or by.repeater or by.css doesn't help as there is only ever 35 items present on the page.

Now to my question, how can i make it so that i can grab all 170 items as an object that i can then iterate through to grab the text of and store as an array?

on other pages where we have less than 35 items iv just used the binding to create an object, then using async.js to go over each row and get text (see below for an example, it is modified extract i know it probably wouldn't work as it is, its just to give you reference)

```
           //column data contains only 35 rows, i need all 170.     
       var columnData = element.all(by.binding('row.entity.name'))
         , colDataTextArr = []
            //prevOrderArray gets created elsewhere
         , prevOrderArray = ['item1', 'item2'... 'item 169', 'item 170'];      

       function(columnData, colDataTextArr, prevOrderArray){
         columnData.then(function(colData){
            //using async to go over each row
           async.eachSeries(colData, function(colDataRow, nRow){
              //get the text for the current async row
             colDataRow.getText().then(function(colDataText){
               //add each rows text to an array
               colDataTextArr.push(colDataText);
               nRow()
             });
           }, function(err){
             if(err){
               console.log('Failed to process a row')
             }else{
               //perform the expect 
               return expect(colDataTextArr).toEqual(prevOrderArray);
             }
           });
         });
       }
```

As an aside, I am aware that iterating through 170 rows and storing the text in an array isn't very efficient so if there is a better way of doing that as well I'm open to suggestions.

I am fairly new to JavaScript and web testing so if im not making sense because I'm using wrong terminology or whatever let me know and i'll try and explain more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is an overkill to test all the rows in the grid. I guess it would be sufficient to test that you get values for the first few rows and then, if you absolutely need to test all the elements, use an evaluate().

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate

Unfortunately there is no code snippet in the api page, but it would look something like this:

```
// Grab an element where you want to evaluate an angular expression
element(by.css('grid-selector')).evaluate('rows').then(function(rows){
  // This will give you the value of the rows scope variable bound to the element.
  expect(rows[169].name).toEqual('some name');
});
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: yeah thats kind of what i think i was going to have to resign to, this part is to mostly test that the sort order is correct and changes accordingly, its just i use this logic on other pages and was being a little lazy, but i think you are right i will test that the first few rows are in the correct order according to the sort order selected, and when i come to actually checking the api response i will evaluate the binding, thanks. marking as correct answer because although not the solution i ideally wanted what you propose is what i'm going to implement.